# Cannot load WSDL using soapClient after call Excel::import() in Laravel

Tags: laravel, soap

I hope anyone can help me.

I cannot load WSDL using soapClient after running excel import using Laravel, My code like this:

```
$import = new TestingImport();
Excel::import($import, storage_path('storage/testing.xlsx'));

$wsdlUrl = route('integration.wsdl', ['xml' => 'testing']);
$opts = [
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false
    ]
];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$soapParameters = [
    'stream_context' => $context,
    'login' => $connection->username,
    'password' => $connection->password,
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'trace' => true,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
];

$soapClient = new \SoapClient($wsdlUrl, $soapParameters);
```

I get this error "failed to load external entity", but if code for importing excel is removed, code SoapClient is running well.

Thankyou everyone.